# Merge Date & Time

Tags: php, html, date, datetime, time

```
$combinedDT = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('$date $time'));
```

Date Format
2013-10-14

time format
23:40:19

i'm getting zeros when trying to store into a datetime datatype

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You're currently doing `strtotime('$date $time')`. Variables wrapped in single-quotes aren't interpolated. If you use single-quotes, PHP will treat it as a literal string, and `strototime()` will try to convert the string `$date $time` into a timestamp.

It'll fail and that would explain why you're getting incorrect results.

You need to use double quotes instead:

```
$combinedDT = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$date $time"));
                                            ^           ^
```

Answer (score 28):

And for those coming here working with DateTime objects:

```
$date = new DateTime('2017-03-14');
$time = new DateTime('13:37:42');

// Solution 1, merge objects to new object:
$merge = new DateTime($date->format('Y-m-d') .' ' .$time->format('H:i:s'));
echo $merge->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // Outputs '2017-03-14 13:37:42'

// Solution 2, update date object with time object:
$date->setTime($time->format('H'), $time->format('i'), $time->format('s'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // Outputs '2017-03-14 13:37:42'
```

Comment: Solution 2 is only proper. First solutions may cause a lot of problems ;)

Comment: @JarekKowol could you explain a bit? What problems are you referring to?

Comment: The second solution preserves the TimeZone